# Почему java программа не освобождает память?

Tags: java, память, jvm, сборщик-мусора

У меня тут творятся очень странные вещи с памятью. Есть главный класс в котором `main` метод запускает множество потоков. Эти созданные потоки через какое то время убиваю,никаких объектов и потоков но память выросла и не освобождается..наблюдаю за всем этим в профайлере(JProfiler). Нет никаких потоков и обьектов кроме `main`, но память все так же стоит и не освобождается, когда запускаю новые потоки память растет с того же места на котором остановилось до этого. т.е. похож на утечку памяти. но вроде никаких утечек нет. В памяти висят не очень много обьектов,самый большой это массив `char[]` Посмотрите на картинках: в диспетчере задач показывает что программа съедает 259 мб.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и на данный момент нет ничего кроме метода `main` который в состоянии `Thread.sleep()`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ниже объекты которые в памяти :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот общие сведения о том сколько жрет моя программа : 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объясните, что тут к чему? Почему если в памяти нет почти никаких объектов  приложение занимает `81 мб`(это то что написано в профайлере). Как будто приложение распухло но внутри ничего нет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У Java есть свой heap, в котором аллоцируются объекты. Когда объект освобождается сборщиком мусора, освобождается место именно в хипе Java, а не в общесистемном. Сборщики мусора могут иметь разные стратегии того, как они отдают память обратно системе.

Кроме того, JVM использует и системный heap для своих нужд, например для стеков ваших потоков (которых вы создаете множество).

Comment: спасибо большое..............

Answer (score 6):

Это обычное поведение JVM. JVM управляет памятью через некоторый промежуточный артефакт, т.н. heap - большой (огромный) кусок памяти, в котором по мере необходимости создаются (и удаляются) объекты, но сам heap как был аллоцирован, так и остается. В целом JVM может отдать часть heap обратно ОС, но прямых способов воздействия на этот процесс нет, плюс из-за характера использования с этим могут быть некоторые проблемы (например, сначала придется компактить содержимое хипа).

Comment: спасибо большое.А почему память растет с того места в котором был до этого? это из-за того что еще GC не очистил память?

Comment: @ЭмЭрИкс_007 если вы подразумеваете заполненность heap, то да, если она растет - кто-то создает объекты, которые потом будут собраны сборщиком мусора. Если вы про сам хип, то он расширяется при необходимости JVM, пока не дойдет до верхней планки (по умолчанию ему разрешено занять всю свободную память)

Comment: а профайлере же не видно что занимает столько памяти?! Значит обьекты с нулевой ссылкой не видны в профайлере?

Comment: @ЭмЭрИкс_007 объекты считаются "живыми" до тех пор, пока не придет GC и не проверит их актуальность. Поэтому да, в этих восьмидесяти мегабайтах может быть произвольное количество мусора. В то же время у вас очень много char[] (должно быть примерно столько же, сколько и String), а основную часть занимают byte[] - я бы принудительно вызвал GC, и, если все это добро останется на месте, у вас скорее всего где-то утечка памяти. Хороший профайлер позволит вам найти ссылки на объект, например, VisualVM это умеет - таким образом вы сможете отследить, откуда эти инстансы.

Comment: спасибо огромное...